# Does the equation $x^3-y^3=b$ have solutions in a finite field $F$ where $b\in F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

> Does the equation $x^3-y^3=b$ has solutions in a finite field $F$ where $b\in F$?

I know it is true for the equation $$x^2-y^2=b\,.$$ As for the case $\text{char}\ F \neq 2$, $$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=b\cdot 1\,,$$ so $x+y=b$ and $x-y=1$ has simultaneous solutions in finite field $F$ for any $b \in F$ namely $$x=\frac{b+1}{2}\text{ and } y=\frac{b-1}{2}\,.$$ The case with $\text{char}\ F=$ $2$ is easy as every element in $F$ is square so put $y=0$ and we can find $x$ easily.

But what about $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy)=b\cdot 1$?

Here it gets complicated a bit, as we do not have two linear equations to solve here. Which subject deals with such questions, I guess algebraic geometry or elliptic curves, I have never had any introduction to any of them, so if someone can suggest a way to attack such question without going too much in those subjects and using field arithmetic mostly, then it will be a lot helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed an elliptic curve. In general, any nonsingular polynomial equation in two variables of degree $d$ defines a plane curve of genus $(d-1)(d-2)/2$. What you've described is actually a twisted Fermat curve. In fact if $b = a^3$ is a cube in $F$, then after replacing $y$ with $-y$ and projectivizing to get the equation $x^3 + y^3 = bz^3$, and then replacing $z/a$ with $z$, then you get $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$, which is precisely the Fermat curve. I can't really answer your question, but perhaps you should google "points on Fermat curves over finite fields"

Comment: In $\Bbb{F}_7$, we have $x^3 \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$ for any $x \in \Bbb{F}_7$. So $x^3 - y^3 = 3$ will have no solution in $\Bbb{F}_7$. I am not sure which condition guarantees the existence of solutions in general, though.

Comment: mostly about cubes: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185278/is-every-number-the-sum-of-two-cubes-modulo-p-where-p-is-a-prime-not-equal-to-7

Comment: If $N$ is the number of solutions to that equation in $\Bbb{F}_q$, then by Hasse-Weil we know that $|N-q|$ has an upper bound $2\sqrt{q}+2$. If this elliptic curve were in Weierstrass form, it would have just one point at infinity. This curve has three (if $3\mid q-1$), so I added two to the bound to be safe. Anyway, if $q>2\sqrt q+2$, or IOW if $q\ge8$, there will be a solution, because $N$ is necessarily positive. We can check the smaller fields individually. As Sangchul Lee pointed out, $q=7$ is problematic. As is $q=4$. A common theme is that cubing is bijective unless $3\mid q-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following theorem can be found in the paper *Multiplicative Subgroups of Index $3$ in a field.* This paper can be accessed [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2047036). The purpose of the paper is to prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a subgroup of index $3$ in the multiplicative group $F^{*}$ of a field $F$. Then $$G+G = F\,,$$ except in the cases $|F| = 4, 7, 13$, or $16.$

Note that $G+G$ is the same thing as $G-G$ in our case since $-1$ is a cube.

The other theorem is

> **Theorem:** Let $K = \mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field. Given any $n$, the equation $$x^n-y^n = K^{*}$$ is not solvable for only finitely many prime powers $q$.

That paper also talks a bit about this and other classical methods can also be used to tackle this problem such as Jacobi sums. Now we look at fields of characteristic $0$. Using Van der Waerden's theorem, Berrizbeitia proved:

> **Theorem:** If $K$ is any field of characteristic zero and $G$ is a subgroup of $K^{∗}$ with finite index, then $$G−G = K\,.$$

The really heavy tools are needed by the authors of [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2159464). Using Ramsey Theory and the fact that there exists a finitely additive invariant probability measure on an ammenable group (like $K^{*}$), the authors were able to prove the analogue of the above state for infinite fields with finite characteristic.

Comment: can you provide some reference for the last claim.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: I actually know the professor who proved it. I will send him a quick email asking for his paper.

Comment: I wonder about how powerful methods you need to prove that last claim? Assuming that $n$ is not divisible by the characteristic the plane curve $x^n-y^n=b, b\neq0,$ is non-singular, and its genus is known (see oxeimon's comment under the question). The Hasse-Weil bound then tells us that the number of points on that curve is positive whenever $q$ is large enough. Enumerating the exact $(q,n)$ pairs where this is not the case does take more work. Proving that to a given $n$ there are only finitely many exceptional $q$ is relatively easy using Hasse-Weil.

Comment: And if $p\mid n$, then you can just apply the Frobenius automorphism and do the exponent $n/p$ instead.

Comment: And a problem in your first claim is that $q=4$ also needs to be excluded. In $\Bbb{F}_4$ all the cubes are in the prime field, so $x^3-y^3\in\Bbb{F}_2$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{F}_4$.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth I have updated my answer with correct information and cited the sources.